# "Cookies not defined" in standalone js-cookie javascript lib?

Tags: javascript, js-cookie

I am not a javascript guru, but try to use js-cookie.
I included the script: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie: I downloaded it ([LINK](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js)), and put it in my own js file on the server.
I then include it in a test file and read some cookie, but it keeps showing me the error "Cookies is not defined" in the browser console. What am I doing wrong :( ?
Code:

```
<html><head>
<script type="javascript" src="https://server/cookies.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("ALL COOKIES: " + Cookies.get());
</script></head>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not used the library, but a quick look at the source code shows that it exports `Cookies` with an uppercase `C`.

```
    if (!registeredInModuleLoader) {
        var OldCookies = window.Cookies;
        var api = window.Cookies = factory();
        api.noConflict = function () {
            window.Cookies = OldCookies;
            return api;
        };
    }
```

So try using the correct case.

```
 console.log("ALL COOKIES: " + window.Cookies.get());
```

Also, everything on `window` is global. So you can simplify the code to this.

```
 console.log("ALL COOKIES: " + Cookies.get());
```

Next time, in the JavaScript console on the browser. Just type `window` and enter to see what variables are global. You can also call it directly in the console to see what happens `Cookies` should print out a JavaScript object with descriptions of what functions it has.

If it's `undefined` then it wasn't loaded or is not global.

**UPDATED:**

The browser is not loading the JavaScript library because the mime-type is wrong. You have to use `application/javascript` as here:

```
      <script type="application/javascript" src="https://server/cookies.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to correct it, after trying some alternatives. Yes, it must be "Cookies.get()", just updated it. I tried your ideas, still not working, also don't see window.Cookies in the browser console. Do I need to call some init method before using it? (it doesn't say in the doc)

Comment: You sure you have the right file name? The file is called `js.cookie.js`

Comment: For this test case I have put the file here: pub.bydehand.com/cookies.js. Looks fine to me

Comment: How stupid :( Thanks, just changed it and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong versions of cookie.js on different routes/pages

Use the Latest

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

If it is not working, then try

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fix :** Just use `window.` before calling it

```
window.Cookies.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @ucMedia's answer, you can add the following line at the beginning of a script to fix any issues.

```
var Cookies = window.Cookies;
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`